# Handling remote notification while app is totally off by launching from app icon

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, notifications, appdelegate

I might by fighting the windmills but I need to put some clearance into my knowledge of **remote notifications**. I want to handle notification while my app is turned off (killed from the app switcher) but user decides to turn it on not by tapping on notification but by tapping on app icon.

As far is I know, when app is killed and a remote notification arrives user has to tap on notification to pass it in `launchOptions` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but... I want to handle this notification when user taps on app icon and nothing is passed to `lauchOptions`. In that scenario, at the moment I have no notification at all...

**Is it possible to handle notification in background and perform action on it no matter how the app has been launched?** Maybe `didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are fighting the windmills :)

I recommend you to read [Local and Push Notifications in depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html). It's a bit long but the doc is clarifying.

In a fragment of this doc you can read:

> If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the
>   application calls the same method
>   (application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:), but furnishes no
>   information about the notification.

And later on:

> When handling remote notifications in
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   applicationDidFinishLaunching:, the application delegate might perform
>   a major additional task. Just after the application launches, the
>   delegate should connect with its provider and fetch the waiting data.
>   Listing 2-5 gives a schematic illustration of this procedure.

So having said this you could have a list of sent notifications for each device in your server and each time your app launches check if the device has any pending notification.

Comment: I wonder why is it so... They should add something like notification queue inside iOS so it would be easier for developer to access those whenever they want!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

> As a result of the presented notification, the user taps the action button of the alert or taps (or clicks) the application icon.
>   If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> **If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification**

So, if your application is launched from the icon then you won't receive the notification data.  You need your app to query the service/data store that is responsible for sending the notification to see if there is outstanding data/transactions/whatever.